# Paste Excel Table into Word Content Control

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a macro that will paste an excel table into a word content control.  The excel table is range named dTable2.  The word content control is wTable2.  This works, but the table inside the word content control is hard to format and manipulate.

```
Application.Goto Sheets("Table Pg 2").Range("dTable2")
Selection.copy
wordDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("wTable2").Item(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
      LinkedToExcel:=False, _
      WordFormatting:=False, _
      RTF:=False
```

Is it possible to paste an enhanced metafile into the word content control?  For my use it is easier to format, etc.  For some reason this does not work. It will paste outside the content control in word.

```
wordDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("wTable2").Item(1).Range.PasteSpecial 
DataType:=EnhancedMetaFile
```

Comment: Try using a RichText type of content control instead of a Picture content control.